# CodeIgniter Custom Admin URI Routes

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

UPDATE: SOLVED! For the broken pages I simply made an admin controller. That has a function for each model now :) Happy days!

Trying to house my admin function in the same controller as my front-end code. To do this I am setting up some custom routes so that admin can be accessed via:

```
/admin/controller/id // instead of /controller/admin/id
/admin/controller/create // instead of /controller/create
/admin/controller/detail/id // instead of /controller/detail/id
/admin/controller/update/id // instead of /controller/update/id
/admin/controller/delete/id // instead of /controller/delete/id
```

My current routes work perfectly for detail, create, update, delete

```
$route['admin/(:any)/detail'] = "$1/detail"; // WORKS!!!
$route['admin/(:any)/detail/(:num)'] = "$1/detail/$2"; // WORKS!!!
$route['admin/(:any)/create'] = "$1/create"; // WORKS!!!
$route['admin/(:any)/create/(:num)'] = "$1/create/$2"; // WORKS!!!
$route['admin/(:any)/update'] = "$1/update"; // WORKS!!!
$route['admin/(:any)/update/(:num)'] = "$1/update/$2"; // WORKS!!!
$route['admin/(:any)/delete'] = "$1/delete"; // WORKS!!!
$route['admin/(:any)/delete/(:num)'] = "$1/delete/$2"; // WORKS!!!
```

HOWEVER I cannot get the admin page to work with an ID. I can reroute the index page, but will be unable to use pagination if I cannot pass the ID.

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "$1/admin"; // WORKS!!!
$route['admin/(:any)/(:num)'] = "$1/admin/$2"; // EPIC FAIL :( 404's
```

Can someone please help me solve this problem, or even suggest an alternative solution of application structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your regex routes (that includes routes with :num and :any) must go AFTER the default_controller route.

For more ways to create a decent admin panel, take a look at my article on [creating an admin panel in CodeIgniter](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter). There are three decent ways to do it, this article explains the pro's and con's of each.

Comment: :) It was that article that solved my little problem. Thanks for checking in ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your admin is complicated and you need several controllers for it, you can simply create an admin folder in your application/controllers folder. Then put your admin controllers in that.

So application/controllers/admin/login would work like http://example.com/admin/login

Comment: Hi, That is the approach I was taking initially, but I wanted to change my approach on a new project and keep CRUD functions within the front-end controller. So I have one controller per function.

Answer (score 0):

Old question that already has an accepted answer, but I think your setup would work fine if you included an end-of-line anchor in your first RegEx:

```
$route['admin/(:any)/(:num)$'] = "$1/admin/$2"; // EPIC FAIL :( 404's
                          ^^^
```

Otherwise URLs you're intending to capture w/ your second RegEx will get intercepted by your first RegEx.